# Create a dynamic sort comparator

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, comparator

I'm a C# developer trying to work on Java. I'm stuck in creating a dynamic comparator. below is the code

```
public class SortImpl implements Sort {
    public SortImpl() {
    }

    public ArrayList<Comparable> sort(ArrayList<Comparable> var1) {
       Comparator var2 = new Comparator() {
       };
       var1.sort(var2);
       return var1;
   }
}
```

But Comparator needs a type while creating a Comparator object. My ArrayList can be of any type like int, double, float. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You are using a *raw* `Comparable`. **Don't**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to implement a `Comparator` at all if you use `java.util.Collections` for sorting the list: it will then be sorted according to the [natural ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) of its elements:

```
public ArrayList<Comparable> sort(ArrayList<Comparable> var1) {
    Collections.sort(var1);
    return var1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I can understand from your code snippet you trying to create sort implementation, not comparator itself.

A `Comparator<T>` is an object that compare two objects.
From JavaDoc:

> int compare(T o1, T o2)
>
> Compares its two arguments for order.
>
> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or  greater than the second.

Because list elements already `Comparable` they can be directly compared as `o1.compareTo(o2)`.

Also sort should be defined as `public <T extends Comparable> List<T> sort(List<T> var1)`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you dont have to implement Comparators for those types (Integer, Float, Char, String, etc...) When you define a List, you will say what type it is:

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

When you sort the list, you may use the Collections.sort(List list, Comparator comparator) method. You may invoke it like:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Person>() {
        public int compare(Personobject1, Personobject2) {
        return 0;//Put your code here
    }
});
```

Parameters:
o1 - the first object to be compared.
o2 - the second object to be compared.
Returns:
a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html for more information